# Magento 2 files to keep in repository

Tags: magento2, git

I started a new Magento 2 project and i always keep my projects in bitbucket...
When i added the files to push i got like 200Mb of files is it really necessary to keep a Magento 2 project in a repository?

I am using [this .gitignore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3/.gitignore) file

Comment: Can you start a new project in a public bitbucket repo so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is necessary to keep in a repository in the context of [Development System Setup](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/development-system.html) of [Pipeline Deployment](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/) is the default [.gitignore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3/.gitignore) that you are using.

There are also build and production system setup documented for pipeline deployment  that are to include additional folders in source control.

The [Development System Setup](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/development-system.html) documentation lays out the recommendation for *"for anyone with a large site who does not want downtime during deployment"* There is also *"a single machine and can tolerate some downtime during deployment, see [Single-machine deployment](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/single-machine.html)"*